# How to get information about nested key attributes from XML data in SnowFlake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have data stored in a VARIANT datatype SnowFlake table.

A row looks like

```
<node id="{~label=recipe, recipeId=2003}">
  <data key="labelV">recipe</data>
  <data key="instructions">Take a salad bowl or platter and line it with lettuce leaves, shortly before serving. Drizzle some olive oil on the leaves and dust them with salt.</data>
  <data key="notes"></data>
  <data key="name">Salade Nicoise</data>
  <data key="recipeId">2003</data>
</node>
```

Now the command

```
SELECT DISTINCT XMLGET(RAW_COLUMN_1, 'data'):"$"::STRING AS "UNIQUE NODES"
FROM "XML_DB_1"."PUBLIC"."XML_TABLE_1"
WHERE RAW_COLUMN_1:"@"::STRING = 'node';
```

gives me the DISTINCT labels like UNIQUE NODES

```
recipe
ingredient
person
book
meal
```

Now if I want to access information about Recipes, I use the command:

```
SELECT *
FROM "XML_DB_1"."PUBLIC"."XML_TABLE_1"
WHERE RAW_COLUMN_1:"@"::STRING = 'node'
AND XMLGET(RAW_COLUMN_1, 'data'):"$"::STRING = 'recipe';
```

which gives me the output of this type:

```
<node id="{~label=recipe, recipeId=2003}">
  <data key="labelV">recipe</data>
  <data key="instructions">Take a salad bowl or platter and line it with lettuce leaves, shortly before serving. Drizzle some olive oil on the leaves and dust them with salt.</data>
  <data key="notes"></data>
  <data key="name">Salade Nicoise</data>
  <data key="recipeId">2003</data>
</node>
```

Now I wish to access the instructions: Take a salad bowl or platter and line it with lettuce leaves, shortly before serving. Drizzle some olive oil on the leaves and dust them with salt.

I hoped the command:

```
SELECT XMLGET(RAW_COLUMN_1,'instruction')
FROM "XML_DB_1"."PUBLIC"."XML_TABLE_1"
WHERE RAW_COLUMN_1:"@"::STRING = 'edge';
AND XMLGET(RAW_COLUMN_1, 'label'):"$"::STRING = 'recipe';
```

would give me the desired output but it just gives me `NULL`. How exactly do we extract data for a particular key in SnowFlake like instructions in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate through the nodes to find one with the `'@key'='instructions'`, you will need to `lateral flatten`:

```sql
create or replace temp table xmls as
select parse_xml('<node id="{~label=recipe, recipeId=2003}">
  <data key="labelV">recipe</data>
  <data key="instructions">Take a salad bowl or platter and line it with lettuce leaves, shortly before serving. Drizzle some olive oil on the leaves and dust them with salt.</data>
  <data key="notes"></data>
  <data key="name">Salade Nicoise</data>
  <data key="recipeId">2003</data>
</node>') RAW_COLUMN_1
union all
select parse_xml('<node id="{~label=recipe, recipeId=2005}">
  <data key="labelV">recipe</data>
  <data key="instructions">Throw potato into microwave</data>
  <data key="notes"></data>
  <data key="name">Microwave potato</data>
  <data key="recipeId">2005</data>
</node>');

select *
from xmls;

select
  get(RAW_COLUMN_1, '@id')::string id
  , get(datanode.value, '$')::string instructions
from xmls, lateral flatten(RAW_COLUMN_1:"$") datanode
where get(datanode.value, '@key')='instructions'
;
```

[image]